# difference between <%= %> and <%: %>

Tags: asp.net

this may be very basic to some people but I have never encountered it before. I was recently going through an MVC tutorial and came across 2 exercises, one used <%= %> the other used <%: %>. Subsequently the first exercise didnt work (although it did in the video I watched) but I have never seen the second notation before. Can anyone explain the difference? Thanx in advance.

Comment: it is not a duplicate of that question (the : vs # makes all the difference in asp.net) but the answer to this question can be found in the comprehensive answer to that post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%:%>
```

That's introduced in Asp.net 4.

Both Renders the output but later one encodes HTML by default.

while using

```
<%=%>
```

you have to explicitly encode HTML input.

For more info, check out Scott Guthrie's blog [post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/06/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx)